# How to validate BLOB object in oracle

Tags: oracle, validation, blob

I have BLOB data (pdf file attachment) in a table.
for us, its too expensive to write Java/ some other code to read BLOB for validate.
Is there any short cut/easy/less expensive way to validate my BLOB? Any command/s to read meta data and validate the BLOB?

Comment: What sort of validation do you have in mind?

Comment: I would like to check whether the BLOB object is corrupted or not.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to check whether the BLOB object is corrupted or not

That's not something you should do in the database. A BLOB is a binary file which is interpreted by the appropriate client software (Adobe Reader, MS Word, whatever). As far as the database is concerned it's a black box. So your application ought to validate the file before it uploads it into the database.

However, there is a workaround. You can build an Oracle Text CONTEXT index on your BLOB column. CONTEXT is really designed for free text searching of documents but indexing is a way to prove that the uploaded file is readable.

The snag with CONTEXT indexes is that they aren't transactional: normally there's a background job running which indexes new documents but for this purpose you would probably want to call `CTX_DDL.SYNC_INDEX()` as part of the upload to present the user with timely feedback. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/ccapp/indexing-with-oracle-text.html#GUID-F6B60A4A-B256-415A-9C54-C67C612BFA9B).

I will reiterate that Text is a workaround, and expensive in terms of database resources. The index itself will consume space and the indexing process requires time and cpu cycles. That's a big investment unless you're going to work with the document inside the database.